# Which one was older, Artemis or Apollo?

Tags: greek, apollo, artemis

On the island of Delos, Leto had twins, Apollo and Artemis.

But usually, twins have a time in between before they are born. Not sure if this is the same in mythology.

So which was older?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most accounts that make the distinction agree that it was Artemis who was born first.

From *Pseudo-Apollodorus, Bibliotheca 1. 21*:

> She [Leto] finally reached Delos and gave birth to Artemis, who thereupon helped her deliver Apollon. Artemis became a practised huntress and remained a virgin.

From *Callimachus, Hymn 3 to Artemis 22*:

> Even in the hour when I [Artemis] was born the Moirai (Fates) ordained that I should be their helper [women in childbirth], forasmuch as my mother suffered no pain either when she gave me birth or when she carried me win her womb, but without travail put me from her body.

<sup>Both quotes from [Theoi](http://www.theoi.com/Olympios/ArtemisMyths.html#Birth).</sup>

Note that some accounts imply that there was a separation between the birth of the twins (see e.g. the references in [*Woman's Power, Man's Game: Essays on Classical Antiquity in Honor of Joy K. King*](https://books.google.com/books?id=adakNcD3Lb0C&pg=PA98&lpg=PA98&dq=who+was+born+first+apollo+or+artemis&source=bl&ots=U1nAKyxhFL&sig=QnJvU6-dKgQC4hROklL4lPm5FNc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjI4YHNmZ7LAhVFnoMKHV9qAB04ChDoAQheMAk#v=onepage&q=who%20was%20born%20first%20apollo%20or%20artemis&f=false)), but this is not explicitly stated anywhere, as far as I know.

Comment: Are those two cited sources from a book (anyone) can find? A library?

Comment: @Sidhartha Apollodorus's *Bibliotheca* can be read [here](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Apollod.+1.1.1), while the hymns of Callimachus can be found [here](http://www.theoi.com/Text/CallimachusHymns1.html).

Comment: In the Roman version, the mother was named  Latona. She turned the "rustics " into frogs because they prevented her from drinking from a pool                        '